# wxPython 2.9 on Mac Os X

Tags: python, wxwidgets, enthought

I am using Enthought Python Distribution (7.2, 64-bit). It comes without wxPython (which is quite important). However, wxPython-2.9 seems to support 64-bit Cocoa interface, so I gave it a try. Actually, it all went good: the command

```
python build-wxpython.py --osx_cocoa --mac_framework --install
```

successfully compiled, and even got into EPD site-packages.
However, a simple wxPython code

```
import wx
wx.App()
```

fails with the following error:

```
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

Can you give me some advice how to cure this? EPD is clearly a Python Framework (i.e., looking at /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework convinces me in it) but this wxPython build does not know about that. The version of wxPython is 2.9.3.1

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this problem yet?

Comment: I don't think so. I switched to PySide though, which works fine for my needs

Comment: Is PySide installation straightforward for EPD64 on OSX 10.7?

Comment: @Mike I have an academic version of EPD (which is non-Free, but if you work in a degree-granting institution, you can get it for free), and PySide is included in it. It is not in the EPD Free, but I suppose that you can just install PySide from sources as usual.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you install `wxpython` with system python. so you can just modify the `main.py` or whatever the other main point your project defined, add at the head like the following:

```
import site
site.addsitedir("/Users/jazz/.pyenv/versions/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/")
```

and then run with `/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

Using a wrapper script like this should setup your environment in such a way that wxPython works correctly:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Real Python executables to use
PYVER=2.7
PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/$PYVER/bin/python$PYVER

# Figure out the root of your EPD env
ENV=`$PYTHON -c "import os; print os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(\"$0\"), '..'))"`

# Run Python with your env set as Python's PYTHONHOME
export PYTHONHOME=$ENV
exec $PYTHON "$@"
```

Just dump it in a file, give it executable permission and use it to launch your wxPython app instead of the python executable.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how this solution works and why there was a problem in the first place using wxPython 2.9 with EPD?

Comment: This solution did not work for me.  Setting PYTHONHOME did not change the error message given in the original question.

Comment: @Mike This solution did not work for me also. It uses the Apple Python which is not the EPD one.

Answer (score 0):

I use anaconda python distribution and encountered the same problem as you described. Namely, "This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac." I don't know if my solution could help you since the setting is different, but you can have a try.

Here is the way I solve this issue:

Step1: install pythonw (I use the command "conda install python.app", but I am sure Enthought must use different command)

Step2: Launch .py file with pythonw instead python.

Hope it helps.